# Working with iOS Swift Date() in NodeJS / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, date

I am posting encoded data that includes Date() variables generated in Swift to a node backend.

An example object that I am encoding:

```
Swift:

let appointmentEncoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(appointment)
```

Results in the following JSON string:

```
[556959600,{"type":"car-wash","date_interval":{"start":557031600,"duration":1800}]
```

The "556959600" is the encoded Date() object of interest. I am able to pass this successfully to a node backend to retrieve.

What I'd like to do is decode the date object to a JavaScript date and encode it back to a date string I can then pass back to Swift.

Is there a way to convert the "556959600" value to a JavaScript date? If so, how would I convert it back to a "556959600" type value?

Comment: Things may be simpler if you setup your `JSONEncoder` so its `dateEncodingStrategy` is set to `.secondsSince1970`. By default the encoder uses a different epoch for dates (see my comment below the answer).

Comment: @rmaddy I ended up going with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Swift time values are seconds since 2001-01-01 (the Swift epoch). Javascript time values are milliseconds since 1970-01-01, so you can multiple the Swift time value by 1000 to make it milliseconds and add the difference between the two time values to get an equivalent javascript time value.

Then use that to make a Date, so:

```js
var swiftOffset = Date.UTC(2001,0,1); // 978307200000
var swiftTV = 556959600;              // Seconds since 2001-01-01

var jsDate = new Date(swiftOffset + swiftTV * 1000);

console.log(jsDate.toString());
```

Comment: TIL about the Swift epoch. Verified this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Date object:

```
var date = new Date(556959600);
```

If you print this var, you'll get `Wed Jan 07 1970 17:42:39`

Comment: Please note that the JSON encoded Swift date is an offset in seconds from the epoch January 1, 2001, 00:00 UTC, not the standard Unix epoch from 1970. So the Javascript Date needs to take that into account.